# File's encoding doesn't work

Tags: html, eclipse, utf-8

In eclipse, I've created a couple of files, added some text and displayed it in the local server. My problem is that instead of utf-8 characters like "ć", "ś" I get some trash like "Ä". All files have .php extension, though it doesn't matter.

Actually, what's strange, with opera some files display those characters properly, while others don't. Using firefox all files show trash.

I've tried project -> properties -> text file encoding -> other (utf-8). It doesn't work.

What's wrong?

It's like that both on localhost and on external servers.

Comment: You have to set the UTF-8 before you put in your text.  Then when you save, it's all good.  Make sure the webpage is set for UTF-8, too.  That always works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the browser what the encoding of the file is. Add a charset tag to the head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Without telling what the encoding is, the browser has to guess. Different browser will make different guesses, some guesses work better for some kind of files, and worse for others.